# Select names of columns that have no data in Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm working on a C# application that imports data from Access into SQL Server. They select an Access file, then a table in the file.

I then perform checks on the data to see if it's valid to import. I want to display a list of columns from the table that have no data in them, so the user has to confirm they want to import regardless of certain empty columns.

Is there an approach to this in Access besides looping through `SELECT ... WHERE (field) IS NULL` queries?

Comment: Do you want to identify which columns are empty on each record, or just get a list of columns that are empty in ALL records?

Comment: AFAIK you are stuck with looping.

Comment: Empty in all records. I have a separate check for four required columns to get specific records that don't have values in them.

Comment: I do not understand the question.  If you want to display which fields are empty, then the only way of knowing that, is to loop through those fields.

Comment: @Ramhound That's pretty much my question. I didn't know if there was any sort of metadata about columns or anything else that could entail a simpler approach.

Answer (score 1):

*Is there an approach to this in Access besides looping through SELECT ... WHERE (field) IS NULL queries?*

I don't know of an alternative to looping, but I will suggest a different strategy for the queries you run in the loop.  Seems to me you would want to know whether any rows include non-Null values for the given field.

```
SELECT Count(*) AS row_count
FROM Table_Name
WHERE field_name Is Not Null;
```

Answer (score 0):

No looping necessary

- Use Count(*) to get the number of total records
- Use Count with WHERE (field) IS NULL and compare the counts
- - If the counts are equal all of the rows are null for that column.

Comment: It still requires looping through the fields collection, does it not?

Comment: ... do you mean loop through the fields collection to build a query SELECT Count(*), Count(Field1) ... Count(Fieldn)?